# In `L[2:4]`, what is `2:4`?

Tags: python, slice

I read that everything is an object in Python. So what is `2:4` in `L[2:4]`? Is it a slicing object? When I just type `2:4` in the interpreter, an `SyntaxError` is raised.

Comment: So `if` is an object too? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `2:4` is not free-standing independent syntax. The syntax *translates* `:`-separtated expressions into a `slice()` object instead, and *only* works in the context of `[]` item indexing. `slice()` is an internal type, see the [internal types documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-59).

`lst[2:4]` is translated to `lst[slice(2, 4, None)]` instead. You can see this when using a custom class with `__getitem__` method:

```
>>> class Demo:
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return item
... 
>>> d = Demo()
>>> d[2]
2
>>> d[2:4]
slice(2, 4, None)
>>> d[2::-2]
slice(2, None, -2)
```

You can create these objects directly, `slice()` is a built-in type:

```
>>> help(slice)
Help on class slice in module builtins:

class slice(object)
 |  slice(stop)
 |  slice(start, stop[, step])
 |  
 |  Create a slice object.  This is used for extended slicing (e.g. a[0:10:2]).
[ ... ]
```

It is the `:` part that triggers the `slice()` object; you can even pass in **multiple** slices, even though no standard-library type supports indexing like that:

```
>>> d[10:, :-5, ::-1, :]
(slice(10, None, None), slice(None, -5, None), slice(None, None, -1), slice(None, None, None))
```

The last slice in that tuple is represented by a single `:` only.

A related object, the `Ellipsis`, is created when you use `...` in your indexing:

```
>>> d[...]
Ellipsis
```

No standard-library type uses this either, but the Numpy project relies heavily on this singleton object and the multiple-slice functionality to do fantastic things to structured data.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows slicing of lists and strings. You need to create an object for L for this syntax to work. Try these as examples:

```
>>> L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> L[2:4]

>>> L = "This is a test"
>>> L[2:4]
>>> L[2:]
>>> L[:4]
>>> L[-3:]
```